# updating a JSON objects value with a for loop in Java Script

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an array of 11 objects which contain JSON data. I wrote a function in which a new key with a zero value is added to each of the objects. Now I want to update the value of the said key in all 11 objects. The data is stored in an array2 with 11 numbers. My for loop doesn't seem to work for this, and the only way to do it (so far) is to hard code it. Does anyone has a suggestion how this can be done?

The desired outcome would be this:

array[0].new_key = array2[0]; 
 array[1].new_key = array2[1];

The first art of the function, before the for loop with j, is for adding the new key into the original array and that part works.

````
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array.map(i => i.new_key = 0);
        console.log(array)
        for (j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            array[i].new_key = array2[j];
            console.log(array)
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: `array[i].new_key = array2[j];`

Comment: I see what I did, thank you for the correction. It still doesn't update the value, it remains zero. I will update the code in OP.

Comment: It's not clear why all this is in these loops. You are looping over `array2` for every item in `array` and you are looping over `array` once in the outer loop and again in the `map()`. It would really help if you gave examples of the data you are starting with and what you wanted as a result.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Well.. I thought I need to loop over the second array in order to assign each value from it, as the outer loop is going over the array with the JSON.  

I want: 

array[0].new_key = array2[0];
array[1].new_key = array2[1];
etc. 

It works if I hard code it like that, but I thought I can shove it all in one function. Sorry if I am being unclear, I am a beginner, and struggling with these complex concepts for me.

Comment: @Nelfo it sound like you want just one for loop, no `map` and `array.new_key[i] = array2[i];` in the loop. But it's hard to tell without concrete data.

Comment: @MarkMeyer what do you mean by concrete data? I am not being sarcastic, I am honestly asking and begging for help. I can't post the whole arrays as the first one is 11 objects filled with enormously lots of data, the second one is just numbers, like this : array2 = [400, 415, 9, 546, 69, 553, 554, 555, 561, 564, 567]. The first array, in all objects I added a key: key_number: '0', and I want that 0 value, to be replaced with the values of the array 2; the 0 index of array to match the number/value of array2 on index 0. I hope I am explaining it better now. And thank you for your effort.

Comment: @Nelfo, yes that's what I mean by concrete. With that it sound like all you need is: `array.forEach((obj, i) => obj.newKey = array2[i] )`

Comment: @MarkMeyer ooh that's even more elegant! Thank you! 
I separated the functions, I realized it was too complicated and it worked. Thanks for your effort, it's truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I split it into two functions, I realized that I made it too complicated and it didn't made sense. I wrote a second function that only updates all the key values, so indeed, I removed the inner loop as it was not needed. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score -1):

<s>`.map()` does not modify the original array:</s>

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

You will want to get the result of the map by assigning it to a variable, and see what is happening there. Right now you don't do anything with it, so it will just disappear.

While the above is true for maps, in this case the original array is being modified as we access the object's properties and modify them there.

Comment: I will take a look at it. I am a beginner, super uncomfortable with the DOM, I haven't thought of using .map(). I will do some reading now. And I am sorry, I have no idea who is down voting all of this.

Comment: You are currently using map on the second line of your function

Comment: .map() isn't the issue here. When the OP does `array.map(i => i.new_key = 0);` they *are* modifying the original array by adding a `new_key` property to each item. That's not a great way to do this, but it *will* modify the original array.

Comment: Yes. I misunderstood your suggestion, then I reread, then I understood I made a moron of myself. >_<

Comment: Ah, @MarkMeyer is actually correct since you are accessing the actual object's properties. Generally you want to return new items in the map, so I agree, probably not the best place to do this. Thanks for the correction.